# Grid sizing between two fixed values?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to set up a grid where the children can only be flexible within two fixed values. Essentially, I want each child to have the same fixed 250px width. Until the parent box shrinks a bit, when I want the children to be able to shrink down just a bit to 240px.

I've tried to set the columns to `minmax(240px, 250px)`, but they stay at 250px.

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 250px)); column-gap: 16px; background: blue">
    <div style="background: red; height: 326px; margin-bottom: 36px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <div style="background: red; height: 326px; margin-bottom: 36px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>    
    <div style="background: red; height: 326px; margin-bottom: 36px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <div style="background: red; height: 326px; margin-bottom: 36px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the slight shrinking effect I'm after? I'm following an organisational style, so have to stick to these confined widths and use only inline css.

Comment: `minmax` is not a suitable width for `auto-fit`

Comment: oh, okay. How do I get the effect I'm after then?

Comment: Use a fixed number of columns? Perhaps switch to flexbox?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YzMyPbb

Comment: I need the boxes to wrap when there's too many for the line, and flexbox doesn't keep the boxes a consistent size once wrapped.

Comment: Then you need media queries but that's hard with inline css.

Comment: Could you outline why shrinking from 250 t0 240 is useful? (as opposed to just having the widths set at 240 to begin with) as a difference of 4% wouldn't seem to be very perceptible to the end user.

Comment: It's because the default, official style is set to 250px. Which is fine for most usages. But there's one particular unfortunately common page view that is locked into a parent box width of 754px, which means 3 250px boxes don't fit (with 16px gap) but I still want to have three on the same line. I realise there's many more elegant ways to set things up (just using 240px the whole time! Actually making use of fr units! Css pages rather than inline styles!), but I'm locked into the system and styles set up by others, and even using 240px rather than 250px is being a bit sneaky.